# Does Yosemite Beta update itself to the final version?

Tags: macos

The title says it all, I think. 
I am installing Yosemite onto a MacPro, and doing it from a Yosemite Beta installer I moved to a thumb drive. It looked like it went well, and it updated itself about 8 times, version 2-6, and then an "OS X Update Combined Version 10.10.5". Does that final update mean I have the full regular install, or is it still a Beta?

Comment: The downvote with no comment is always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No - in general, the builds that are GM Candidates are marked as final and you need to go install the correct update intentionally. Sometimes a 10.x.1 update arrives in time for you to jump on that automatic update, but you should follow the specific directions bases on how you obtained the beta for how to get back on release updates. The steps differ for different programs.

Comment: Thank-you. With all the updates that took, I'm still curious to understand what the difference is between what I have and a non-beta installation.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer One difference is if your Mac has a profile that enables beta updates through the app store. The other would be the pure code changes between any two arbitrary builds. You could use a file comparison tool like Kaleidoscope or use Time Machine `tmutil compare` to compare what changed between backup intervals or the current system and a specific snapshot time. Since you put combo updates on top of a build that might be missing some frameworks, you could have some oddball missing items or everything could be totally replaced...